# Custom фильтр django admin

Tags: django, django-admin, django-filter

Суть задачи следующая нужно как то сделать не самый простой фильтр. Есть 2 модели в разных приложениях.

```
# Приложение Blocks - файл models.py
class Block(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    description = models.TextField()
    status = models.BooleanField(default = True)

# Приложение Sites - файл models.py
from apps.blocks.models import Block

class Site(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 255, )
    description = models.TextField()
    blocks = models.ManyToManyField(Block)
```

И мне нужно модель `Block` отфильтровать по полю `name` модели `Site`.

**Пример:**

Есть три записи в модели `Block`: <Запись 1>, <Запись 2>, <Запись 3>,
а в модели `Site` две записи: <Ресурс 1>, <Ресурс 2>.

Когда я захожу в `admin django` в модель `Block` я хочу видеть в фильтре все `Site` которые которые связанны хотя бы с одним `Block`.

Как вы делаете подобные фильтры. Извините за моё странное объяснение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы увидеть в фильтре все `Site`, которые связанны хотя бы с одним `Block`, вам необходимо переопределить метод `lookups`, внутри которого вы вычислите `id` и `name` тех `Site`, которые вам необходимо отображать (пример ниже). Поле `id` - будет для внутреннего использования, `name` - для отображение в панели администратора.

Далее в методе `queryset` вы можете отфильтровать объекты `Blocks` по выбранному пользователем значению, если пользователь пока ничего не выбрал, то ничего нечего не делается.

Ниже привожу примерный код фильтра:

```py
class SiteFilter(admin.SimpleListFilter):

    title = 'Фильтр по Site'
    parameter_name = 'site_id'
    field_name = 'site__id'

    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        """Доступныe фильтры по Site."""
        queryset = model_admin.get_queryset(request)
        sites = Site.objects.filter(block__in=queryset).distinct()
        for site in sites:
            yield (site.id, site.name)

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        site_id = self.value()
        if site_id:
            return queryset.filter(**{self.field_name: site_id})
        return queryset
```

Comment: Большое вам спасибо. Это то что нужно.